# Creating permutations of operators between variables

Tags: c++, permutation

Let's say I have the following input vectors

```
vector<string> variables = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
vector<string> operators = { "+" };
```

As a result I would like to get all different permutations of operators between these variables. Variables are always on fixed locations - only the operators change.

For previous input vectors I need to have the following output:

```
A + B + C + D
```

This is simple as only one operator is available ("+"). But, if I have the following input vectors:

```
vector<string> variables = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
vector<string> operators = { "+", "-" };
```

then the following output would be required:

```
A + B + C + D
A - B + C + D
A + B - C + D
A + B + C - D
A - B - C + D
A + B - C - D
A - B + C - D
A - B - C - D
```

Now I have all possible variations of those operators between variables.

So far I wrote the following function

```
template<class T>
vector<vector<T> > getAllPermutations(vector<T> input) {
    vector<vector<T> > res;
    do {
        vector<T> current_vector;
        for (T index : input)
            current_vector.push_back(index);
        res.push_back(current_vector);
    } while (next_permutation(input.begin(), input.end()));
    return res;
}
```

but this only solves part of the problem, as I don't know how to generate proper input vector each time I need to call this function.

How to solve this?

Comment: You don't include, for example, `B - A - C + D` (or equivalently, `- A + B - C + D`)?

Comment: @lurker Actually, no. Both situations are not possible. Variables cannot change locations. Only the operators.

Comment: The number of permutations of a sequence is (length!), but the number of choices of operators you want here is pow(number of choices, number of positions). Permutations aren't the solution; an odometer-style algorithm is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Here is another version using just loops:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<string> make_combinations(
    const vector<string>& variables, const vector<string>& operators)
{
    vector<string> out;
    if (variables.empty()) return out;
    auto num_combs = pow(operators.size(), variables.size() - 1);
    out.reserve(num_combs);
    string current;
    for (size_t i_comb = 0; i_comb < num_combs; i_comb++)
    {
        current += variables[0];
        auto num = i_comb;
        for (size_t i_var = 1; i_var < variables.size(); i_var++)
        {
            current += " ";
            current += operators[num % operators.size()];
            current += " ";
            num /= operators.size();
            current += variables[i_var];
        }
        out.push_back(current);
        current.clear();
    }
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> variables = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
    vector<string> operators = { "+", "-" };
    auto out = make_combinations(variables, operators);
    for (const auto& str : out)
    {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is the same as before, although in different order.

---

This is a simple recursive algorithm to do that:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void make_combinations_rec(
    vector<string>::const_iterator varsIt, vector<string>::const_iterator varsEnd,
    const vector<string>& operators, vector<string>& out, string& current)
{
    // Add current variable
    current += *varsIt;
    auto rem = varsIt->size();
    // Check if this was the last variable
    if ((++varsIt) == varsEnd)
    {
        // Add complete expression
        out.push_back(current);
    }
    else
    {
        // For every operator
        for (auto& op : operators)
        {
            // Add operator surrounded by whitespace
            current += " ";
            current += op;
            current += " ";
            make_combinations_rec(varsIt, varsEnd, operators, out, current);
            // Remove operator
            current.erase(current.size() - op.size() - 2);
        }
    }
    // Remove variable
    current.erase(current.size() - rem);
}

vector<string> make_combinations(
    const vector<string>& variables, const vector<string>& operators)
{
    vector<string> out;
    if (!variables.empty())
    {
        // Reserve space in advance
        out.reserve(pow(operators.size(), variables.size() - 1));
        string current;
        make_combinations_rec(
            variables.begin(), variables.end(), operators, out, current);
    }
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> variables = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
    vector<string> operators = { "+", "-" };
    auto out = make_combinations(variables, operators);
    for (const auto& str : out)
    {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A + B + C + D
A + B + C - D
A + B - C + D
A + B - C - D
A - B + C + D
A - B + C - D
A - B - C + D
A - B - C - D
```

Answer (score 1):

For one possible solution it could help if you look at the size of `operators` as a numeric base and the size of `variables` (minus one) as the number of digits in a number represented by the base. So for you example with `"+"` and `"-"` you have two `operators` which means the base is `2` which is simple as it's binary arithmetic. If you have four `operators` (by adding e.g. `"*"` and `"/"`) then the base is `4`. The number of "digits" in the number you create using the base will (with your example) be `variables.size() - 1`, or `3`.

Create the permutations using the numbers, so with the (binary) example in your question it would be

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Then use the digits of this collection of numbers as translation to get the operators between each variable. That is `0` represents `operators[0]` which is`"+"` and `1` represents `operators[1]` which is `"-"`.

Solving this for any generic base B and number of digits D is a little harder, but it's an old and long solved problems with plenty of descriptions, algorithms and examples available.

Comment: That's interesting approach... And it would probably work. But I am more interested if there is some "standardized" solution already for this kind of problem.

Comment: @Tracer This is simply a base `n` odometer.

Answer (score 1):

You want all permutations *with repetition* (a.k.a. [n-tuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)) of the available operators. It is very easy to write a generic function to generate all n-tuples of a given length. Here is an an iterative solution:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> n_tuples(std::initializer_list<T> a, std::size_t const n)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> tn = {{}};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        auto tn_1 = std::move(tn);
        for (auto const& x : a) {
            for (auto const& t : tn_1) {
                t.push_back(x);
                tn.push_back(t);
            }
        }
    }
    return tn;
}
```

Here is how you would use it in your case:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<char> vars = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
    for (auto const& ops : n_tuples({'+', '-'}, vars.size() - 1)) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < ops.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << vars[i] << " " << ops[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << vars.back() << "\n";
    }
}
```

This gives the output:

```
A + B + C + D
A - B + C + D
A + B - C + D
A - B - C + D
A + B + C - D
A - B + C - D
A + B - C - D
A - B - C - D
```

Note that `n_tuples` handles the case where `n == 0` correctly (by returning a vector containing a single empty vector -- the *0-tuple*), so it will work nicely even with a single variable.